# How do I get version text for an "About..." box in Java?

Tags: java

I have a **Java application**, running from a `jar`; I need to show version number in a classic `"About..."` box (telling **"My Application, version 1.0.0"**, that's all).

Given that I save that string in a **`MANIFEST.MF`** file, how do I retrieve it at runtime?

I tried

```
swVersion = Main.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

but it returns a `null`. In my jar, under `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, I have a property like

```
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
```

which is usually a working example, is it?

Comment: In the javadoc from Packige: **Implementation Note:**
The builtin class loaders do not explicitly define Package objects for packages in _**named** modules_. Instead those packages are automatically defined and have no specification and implementation versioning information.

Comment: @MartinZeitler The thread is interesting, however note that the OP didn't receive a working answer, in the end. Still experienced the same issue, as in my case. Even the answer to run *outside* the IDE isn't working in my case as well, the result is still /null/